# Refresh the global address book in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I refresh the address list cache in Outlook 2010? Some addresses aren't showing up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Your issue is addresses are not showing and you are asking how to delete them?

Comment: How to refresh them, deleting the cache or something like that

Comment: Are you talking about the global address book or the auto complete?

Comment: global address book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Outlook 2010, select the File tab in the upper left corner, then
> Download Address Book from the Account Settings drop down menu.
>
> Outlook 2007 users should select Tools from Outlook's uppermost menu,
> then Send/Receive and Download Address Book from the Tools drop down
> menus.
>
> The Offline Address Book window will appear. Make sure the following
> options are selected:
> De-check the Download changes since last Send/Receive option
> Make sure Full Details is selected
> Make sure the \Global Address List is selected from the Choose address book drop
> down menu
>
> Click the OK button at the bottom. The most recent version of the
> Global Address List will be downloaded from the CUMC IT Exchange
> server. You may see a status window indicating the download's
> progress, it will automatically disappear when completed.
>
> Close  Outlook when the download has finished. Re-open Outlook and log in;
> the Global Address List should now contain the most recent
> information.

[Source](http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/exchange/gal.html)